# Which wording is more correct and common ("introduced to" or "included in")?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Original:

> Он внесен во всемирную еврейскую энциклопедию.

The meaning of the sentence is that the person has been placed in the encyclopedia. The life of this man and his contribution to the history was so significant that information about him has been placed in the encyclopedia.
Could you please help me to choose the most correct wording:

> 1. He is introduced to the World Jewish Encyclopedia.
> 2. He is included in the World Jewish Encyclopedia.
> 3. Maybe there is a better wording?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Both of them are grammatically correct, but they don't mean the same thing, and you didn't say what you wanted the sentence to mean (since most of us here can't read Russian.)  Did you look up the word "[introduce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/introduce)"?  I don't think there's any sense of the word "introduce" that means the same thing as "included in".

Comment: You have to explain the surrounding context and what the original sentence is **trying** to express. This way, we can better determine which word might be appropriate.

Comment: @stangdon The meaning of the sentence is that the person has been placed in the encyclopedia. The life of this man and his contribution to the history was so significant that information about him has been placed in the encyclopedia.

Comment: @Max The meaning of the sentence is that the person has been placed in the encyclopedia. The life of this man and his contribution to the history was so significant that information about him has been placed in the encyclopedia.

Comment: @stangdon: Consider [*For example : "selfie" can replace "self portrait ". It's more convenient and also more prevalent and therefore **was introduced into the dictionary***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+introduced+into+the+dictionary%22#tbm=bks&q=%22therefore+was+introduced+into+the+dictionary%22) Which seems fine to me, but I think when we want that *[finally] **included** in [some exalted category or "list"]* sense, it works much better with ***into*** rather than ***in***.

Comment: @Maxim: As implied by comments and answers, using ***introduced*** for the meaning you want is relatively unusual, and may well be misunderstood (partly because it's a rather "formal" usage that won't be encountered often). In more natural speech most native speakers would be far more likely to say something like *He **made it into** the World Jewish Encyclopedia.*

Comment: As evidence of which, consider these 99 written instances of [*made it into Who's Who*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22made+it+into+who%27s+who%22) (the British equivalent to the "famous people" section of the World Jewish Encyclopedia, I suppose).

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Is the sentence really about the insertion of the article? Doesn't it simply mean that there *is* an article?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much for the example! The version with "introduced" I received using an online translator, it seemed strange to me too, but I guess that is a common wording  that is not familiar to me. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @DavidC That's right, I mean that there is an article about the man in the encyclopedia, but it was made some time ago in the past. I'm sorry if my explanation was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be completely clear, I think the correct wording should be "He was (or 'has been') **added to** the World Jewish Encyclopedia."

"Is included" sounds to me like he exists in the encyclopedia, but doesn't suggest that he has become part of it *recently*. "Is introduced" might be technically correct, but to me, that seemed to suggest that he *recently learned of* the encyclopedia, since the subject of the sentence is a person and not a thing.

---

Perhaps an even more intuitive way to describe it would be to use the encyclopedia **entry** as the subject of the sentence, e.g. "An entry about him was recently introduced to..." or "His entry is now included in...". Using the *person* as the subject makes verbs like "included," "joined," etc. seem strange because *people* aren't in encyclopedias, really. Using such verbs makes it seem as though they joined a club. (Which, in context, may make sense to your readers if "joining" the World Jewish Encyclopedia is viewed as a prestigious event.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of interesting nuances. In case, if I misled you, I wanted to say that there is an article about the man in the encyclopedia, but it was made some time ago in the past. The presence in this encyclopedia is indeed a sign of recognition of human merit. Thank you again!

Comment: @MaximVelichkin ah. Yeah, the phrase “has been placed” threw me off since it puts the importance on him _being added to_ the volume. But either way, glad I could help clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

Your are translating from a language in which specific verbs are preferred to one where "to be" is the verb of choice. The idiomatic English expression is:

> There **is** an article about him in the World Jewish Encyclopedia.

The first possibility which you suggest is incorrect:

> He **is introduced** to the World Jewish Encyclopedia.

To "introduce to" means "to make acquainted". You probably meant "introduced into". This sense of the word is now little known and may never have been used in cases such as this.

The second possibility you suggest is an acceptable literal translation:

> He **is included** in the World Jewish Encyclopedia.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Both answers helped me a lot and suggested a great options, so I mark an earlier response, but thank you very much to both of you!